# lnd stoped routing - unable to update fee rate

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, lightning-routing

I used to have about 5 routings per day. Now, since three days I don't have any routing. In my lnd.log I find lines like this:

```
grep ERR lnd.log
2021-09-19 22:40:53.187 [ERR] HSWC: ChannelLink(700510:557:1): unable to update fee rate: cannot apply fee_update=1419 sat/kw, new balance=0.00007673 BTC would dip below channel reserve=0.00015 BTC
2021-09-19 23:11:00.999 [ERR] HSWC: ChannelLink(700510:557:1): unable to update fee rate: cannot apply fee_update=1419 sat/kw, new balance=0.00007673 BTC would dip below channel reserve=0.00015 BTC
2021-09-19 23:23:01.180 [ERR] HSWC: ChannelLink(700510:557:1): unable to update fee rate: cannot apply fee_update=1419 sat/kw, new balance=0.00007673 BTC would dip below channel reserve=0.00015 BTC
2021-09-19 23:42:23.031 [ERR] HSWC: ChannelLink(700510:557:1): unable to update fee rate: cannot apply fee_update=1419 sat/kw, new balance=0.00007673 BTC would dip below channel reserve=0.00015 BTC
```

*(changed the channel-id here)*

Seems like I have insufficient local funds on one channel. Can this error be the reason that all channels (about 50) to stop routing? And how can I (from anything like lncli listchannels) find what channel that is (700510:557:1)? I find only the uint64 notations for the short channel id.

And, finally, how I can I solve that problem?

Thanks!

P.S. Meanwhile found the channel (700510:557:1) at amboss.space.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is about trying to update the onchain fees in the case of a force close. The onchain fees are renegotiated with your peer from time to time, so that you are safe in case your partner becomes unresponsive. From your log file, it looks like your channel has most of its balance on the remote side and thus you could not afford the higher onchain feerate which your node attempted to set.

With respect to routing I guess (!) you ran into a typical issue of setting your routing fees too low after announcing the channel. In that case people might quickly use your channel for rebalancing and to get themselves the liquidity to where they believe it will be used best in the future. This would explain why you don't route anymore on that channel. Of course you could rebalance which will cost you money or just wait until money flows in the other direction.

Comment: Thanks Rene. I understand this, but have two other problems. (1) All other channels (about 48) also have no routings anymore. (2) also, I can't rebalance onto that channel, https://github.com/C-Otto/rebalance-lnd gives me a "Temporary channel failure" on each possible route to fill the outbound liq. on that "broken" channel.

Comment: Maybe the best thing I could do is a cooperative close on the empty channel?

Comment: Ok, I've restarted LND (after 30 days uptime) and had two routings after 7 minutes to different channels. To me this looks like a bug. I'll post something to a github issue.

Comment: If rebalance-lnd only gives "temporary channel failure", there might not be enough (cheap enough) liquidity on the routes you're attempting. You may need to increase the fees you're willing to pay (`--fee-factor` with a value > 1, maybe even `--reckless`).